# Unmarshal comma-separated string or int values in json to an array

Tags: arrays, json, go

I have a piece of code that collects key/value store into json. Now key value store may contain array as a value, below is the json

```
{
  "name":"abc",
  "address":"some address value",
  "phonenumber": "\"123123\",\"7897897\",\"45345345\""
}
```

and I want to unmarshal this to below struct

```
type myobj struct{
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Address string `json:"address`
  PhoneNumbers []string
}
```

the phonenumbers field is a comma separated list in json, and I want to unmarshal this to an array of strings, how to I go about this?

Comment: You simply **cannot** do this without doing manually. You can post process the unmarshaled string or you can make myobj implement https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler . As usual: read the whole package doc first.

Comment: @Pharaoh Implement the Unmarshaler interface, as suggested by Volker (https://play.golang.com/p/4MUZFZdz1Yi)

Answer (score 2):

You can unmarshal it to a string and then split it.

```golang
type myobj struct{
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Address string `json:"address`
  PhoneNumberRaw string `json:"phonenumber"`

  PhoneNumbers []string `json:"-"`
}

// Unmarshal.
var o myobj
json.Unmarshal(yourData, &o)

// Remove the quotes and split the phone number string by comma.
o.PhoneNumbers = strings.Split(strings.ReplaceAll(o.PhoneNumberRaw, `"`, ""), ",")
```

Comment: The resulting elements in `PhoneNumbers` will still have leading and trailing double-quotes.